# Look for ReSharper 5.0 Menu Map

Tags: resharper

I have found this ReSharper 5.0 Default Key Map
http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/docs/ReSharper50DefaultKeymap_IDEA_scheme.pdf

I would like to find a corresponding Menu Map so that I know where each command is located in the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no such document exists. We've been considering writing one for some time, but there's still no tangible result.
The closest one that we have is [ReSharper Feature Map](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/feature_map.html) but it's been a while since it was last updated.